# Xcode: Value of type 'GameView' has no member 'view'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I trying to make something using Xcode playgrounds. when I try to use the auto layout function, I get an error message displaying 
Value of type 'GameView' has no member 'view'

Here is my code, there is some more but I've only added the parts that are relevant.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
public class GameView : UIView{
self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1500, height: 1000))

    }
    public override func addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        self.view.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            ])
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might never assigned `GameView` Class to any `UIview`. would you please show your console result when debugging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ues "self" instead of "self.view".
And you should use GameView.self.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
public class GameView : UIView{
    override public init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1500, height: 1000))

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    public override func addConstraints(_ constraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]) {
        self.addConstraints([
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 64),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: GameView.self, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0),
            ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't have a `view` property, I think you want to use just `self`. You probably copied this code from some kind of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Ah yes I did, so what do you recommend doing? I tried removing both of them separately and a string of errors popped up.

Comment: Well this code looks kinda messy, you should setup your constraints in `UIViewController` subclass either using interface builder or `loadView` method in code.